# How to add the same icon after multiple li elements that were created with document.createElement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner making a to-do app.

Once a user inputs a task, I create a list item for that task. However i have no idea how to add a delete icon after the newly created li. Below is my code. Please assist.

```
const inputArea = document.querySelector('#input');
const allTasks = document.querySelector('#list');
const deleteTask = document.querySelector('#close');

function collectInfo() {
  if (inputArea.value === '') {
    alert('please type a task to add');
  } else if (inputArea.value != '') {
    const node = document.createElement('li');
    const newTask = allTasks.appendChild(node);
    newTask.textContent = inputArea.value;
  }
}

const clicked = document.querySelector('#add');
clicked.addEventListener('click', collectInfo);
```

Comment: please attach your html code

Answer (score 0):

In your function you can also add the tasks via another way. Instead of appending you can add each task by using +=, wich gives you another approach to easily add the delete button

```
function collectInfo() {
  if (inputArea.value === '') {
    alert('please type a task to add');
  } else if (inputArea.value != '') {
    allTasks += `<tr><td>${inputArea.value}</td><td><button 
    id="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>`
  }
}
```

In this example I used a table structure if you want to use the same structure.
Change your #list to <table id="list>

After this you still need to link the delete button with your new task.

In the current case you can do this by giving each task an unique id that you can link to the button by that id.

A second completely different method you could use is to store each new task in an Array, then use a foreach loop to display the tasks and link the delete button to the index of the array.